# Implementation of hashing and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, caching, hash

Let's take this code which does nothing really interesting.  It creates a dictionary with a single key `'x' * N` (`N` being an argument of the script), then accesses this item 10000000 times and prints the execution time.

```py
import sys, time

X = 'x' * int(sys.argv[1])
LOOPS = 10000000
attrs = {X: 1}
t1 = time.time()
n = 0
for _ in range(LOOPS):
    n += attrs[X]
    attrs[X] += 1
t2 = time.time()
print(t2 - t1)
```

I launched it with different values of `N` in {1, 10, 100, 1000} and I did not observe any increase of the execution time (around 2.8 seconds each time on my machine).  I was expecting some as my first guess was that each access to `attrs` would cause an hash value to be computed for `'x' * N`.  So I'm curious about the magic behind this.  Is there some caching mechanism applied?  Or am I wrong about my assumption on the implementation of dictionaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's implementation of `str.__hash__()` caches the hash the first time it's computed for that string, so the hash only has to be computed once for any given string.

Some (but not all) other immutable objects do the same sort of caching.  See https://bugs.python.org/issue1462796 (a rejected request to apply the same caching logic to tuples).

Comment: ok good to know. I just put ```X = X[:-1] ; X += 'x'``` in my loop which seems to clear the cache and now I can see a runtime increase.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The value/length of 'X' variable is changing based on your input i.e.,  {1, 10, 100*, 1000}.  This means the memory used to store the variable is increasing with your input size.
The value of X is used in a dictionary and is used only to hash/index the value in the dictionary.  In the dictionary, the hashing is done by internally storing the address of the index.   Due to this hash/index, the time to access the value is the same irrespective of the length of X.   This is the reason for the CPU time taken to be constant.

Comment: This answers the question of why you can get the value in constant time given the hash, but it doesn't answer the question of why determining the hash itself is also (amortized) constant time!  :)